# Tricky combination question.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

**Problem:** In a factory there are 1,2,3,4 & 5 departmens. Choose two persons from each department and place them in a line so that there is one person between the two persons from dept. 1, two persons stand between the persons from dept. 2, three persons stand between the persons from dept. 3. etc. Is this arrangement possibe? if so, how?

---

I have no attempt really I can't figure out how to use math on this problem. Isn't it just to get 10 random peices of post-it papers with different colors and try to arrange them? I can't see "the catch" in this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Label the positions, left-to-right, as $1,2,3,...,10$.

Suppose there is some arrangement which satisfies the specified conditions.

Let $x_k,y_k$ with $x_k < y_k$ be the positions of the two people from department $k$.

\begin{align*}
\text{By hypothesis,}\;\,&y_k - x_k = k+1,\;\text{for all k}\\[4pt]
\text{hence}\;&\sum_{k=1}^5(y_k-x_k)=\sum_{k=1}^5(k+1)=20\\[4pt]
\implies\;&\sum_{k=1}^5y_k-\sum_{k=1}^5 x_k=20\\[8pt]
\text{But also}\;&\sum_{k=1}^5y_k+\sum_{k=1}^5 x_k=1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + 10 = 55\\[8pt]
\text{hence}\;&
\left(\sum_{k=1}^5y_k+\sum_{k=1}^5 x_k\right)+
\left(\sum_{k=1}^5y_k-\sum_{k=1}^5 x_k\right)
=55 + 20\\[4pt]
\implies\;&2\sum_{k=1}^5y_k = 75\\[4pt]
&\text{contradiction, since}\\[4pt]
&2\sum_{k=1}^5 y_k\;\text{must be even.}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Using the argument about the parity of positions, it is easy to prove that such an alignement is impossible if the number $n$ of departments is congruous to $1$ or $2$ modulo $4$: $n\hspace{2,pt} mod\hspace{2,pt} 4 \in \{1,2\} \implies (no \hspace{2,pt} solution)$.

If $n=3$ or $n=4$, we can provide solutions such as $(312132)$ and $(41312432)$.
Could anyone find solutions for $n=7$ or $n=8$ ? Prove whether a solution exists for each $n$ s.t. $n\hspace{2,pt} mod\hspace{2,pt} 4 \in \{3,0\}$ ?

Comment: I posed your question in a new thread:$\;$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2304703, and I show solutions for $n=7$ and $n=8$.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily show this to be impossible by looking at the possible parities of their locations, i.e. whether the two persons from the same dept end up both on even or odd locations, or whether one ends up on an odd and the other on an even location, where you number the locations as 1 through 10.

For example, with 1 person between them, the two people from dept 1 end up both being in an odd-numbered location, or both on an even-numbered location. The same goes for the two persons from dept 3, and the two from 5.  But the locations from thw two people from dept 2 will have the opposite parity, and that is also true for the two from dept 4.

So: the number of people on an even numbered location will be 2,4,6, or 8 ... but the number of even numbered locations is 5. So, it can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

Number the positions in the line from $1$ to $10$.  For two of the pairs of people (departments $2$ and $4$), you'll be standing them at positions of opposite parity: one even, one odd.  For the other three pairs, you'll stand them at positions of the same parity: both even or both odd.  In the whole line, there are $5$ positions of each parity; after placing departments $2$ and $4$, there are $3$ positions of each parity left.  Since the remaining departments must use up an even number of positions of each parity, you can't place them all.

You can definitely solve this one by trial and error.  But note that the parity-based solution has a powerful generalization: it works for many factory sizes simultaneously.  Can you see which factory sizes (i.e., what numbers of departments) are ruled out?